# Could this usage of AutoResetEvent be causing the issue described?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, autoresetevent

I am not used to working with `AutoResetEvent`, and am wondering how the following could occur.

We have a log file that is consistently recording a different order of loading operations on two different machines :

Machine A (problem occurring)

```
Loading Module A
Loading Module B
Loading Shell.
Show Window.
Waiting Until Services are Loaded & Initialized.
Loading Module C
Starting Application ..
```

Machine B (normal log file)

```
Loading Module A
Loading Module B
Loading Module C
Starting Application ..
Loading Shell.
Show Window.
Initializing Menu Elements ...
```

The first machine never loads the Menu Elements.

The code is something like this :

```
public class SplashScreen : Form
{
    // SplashScreen.Run method which signals the ProgressCompleted event
    private void Run()
    {
        // some code

        MySingleton.Instance.ExecutionCompleted.WaitOne();
        MySingleton.Instance.Completed = true;
        MySingleton.Instance.ProgressCompleted.Set();

        // more code
    }
}

public class ShellApplication : FormShellApplication<WorkItem, ShellForm>
{    
    // ShellApplication.Start override
    protected override void Start()
    {
        MySingleton.Instance.ProgressCompleted.WaitOne();
        WriteToLog("Starting Application ..");
        base.Start();
    }
}

public class ShellForm : Form
{    
    // Background worker that runs from ShellForm.Load
    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // check to ensure services & ui components are loaded & initialized 
        if (!MySingleton.Instance.Completed)
        {
            WriteToLog("Waiting Until Services are Loaded & Initialized.");
            MySingleton.Instance.ProgressCompleted.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    // Background worker’s RunWorkerCompleted that runs from ShellForm.Load
    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some Code
        WriteToLog("Initializing Menu Elements ...");
    }
}
```

The singleton uses an `AutoResetEvent` for `ExecutionCompleted` and `ProgressCompleted`, and a bool with a sync lock for the `Completed` flag

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private object _sync = new object();

    private static AutoResetEvent _executionCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static AutoResetEvent _progressCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private static bool _completed = false;

    public AutoResetEvent ProgressCompleted
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _progressCompleted;
            }
        }
    }

    public AutoResetEvent ExecutionCompleted
    {
        get 
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _executionCompleted;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Completed
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _completed;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                _completed = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, it looks like on Machine A the background worker starts before all the modules load, and `ProgressCompleted.WaitOne()` is either never hit or is hit while the `.Completed` flag is false. I don't have enough experience with `AutoResetEvent` to know if anything in the code would be causing this, such as the second `.WaitOne` call to it.

I don't think it's a timing issue related to the sync lock because it consistently happens every single time on Machine A, while I am unable to reproduce the problem on Machine B (my machine).

Is there anything in the code above related to the `AutoResetEvent` usage that could cause this abnormal behavior? I am using .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using `ManualResetEvent` instead of `AutoResetEvent`.

Reset events are like a stoplight. Since you initialize it with `false` it starts as a red light.
When you `set` it, it turns to green.
The difference between `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent` is how much time it stays on green...

`ManualResetEvent` will stay on green until somebody calls `Reset` on it.
`AutoResetEvent` will let one car enter and automatically revert to a red light again.
You set `ProgressCompleted` once but you wait on it twice, first time in `ShellApplication.Start`, and the second time in `worker_DoWork`. Meaning the second wait will wait forever.

The reason it won't always fail is because of the `if (!MySingleton.Instance.Completed)` which dictates that you don't wait for the reset event the second time if the splash screen code was faster than the background worker.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected this might be the case, but I was having trouble finding any specific examples online... I didn't think to compare it with a ManualResetEvent. I finally did get around to making a sample project that can confirm this. I like your car analogy too :)